# Stripe with Firebase doesn't seem to find the ephemeral keys

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, stripe-payments

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239322/swift-firebase-stripe-connect) answers tutorial and tutorials in the links in order to setup the stripe with Firebase. The server is setup, and works fine in the webbrowser (index.hmlt page). But when I try to use stripe in my iOS app i recieve this following error (404, shown bellow).

Thanks in advance!

> **Error : FAILURE: responseValidationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(404))**

From `MyAPIClinent.swift`

```
func createCustomerKey(withAPIVersion apiVersion: String, completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {
            let url = self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("ephemeral_keys")
            Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: [
                "api_version": apiVersion,
                "customer_id" : "cus_DDVQ3OSLzdnf4X"
                ])
                .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
                .responseJSON { responseJSON in
                    print(responseJSON)
                    switch responseJSON.result {
                    case .success(let json):
                        completion(json as? [String: AnyObject], nil)
                    case .failure(let error):
                        completion(nil, error)
                    }
}
```

From `index.js`

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const logging = require('@google-cloud/logging')();
//const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.token);
const currency = functions.config().stripe.currency || 'SEK';

var express = require('express');
var stripe = require('stripe')('MY_SECRET_TOKEN');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended : true
}))

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.post('/ephemeral_keys', (req, res) => {
  var customerId = req.body.customer_id;
  var api_version = req.body.api_version;

  stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
    {customer : customer_id},
    {stripe_version : apiversion}
  ).then((key) => {
    res.status(200).send(key)
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).end()
  });
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: And I only use phone authentication if that matters?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem, did you found a solution?